# JQuery : Change value off multiple placeholders dynamically

Tags: jquery

I have 4 inputs with different placeholders, I need when a user change/select another language all the placeholders changes.
How can I change the string in all placeholders with jquery on change country?
Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change an HTML5 input's placeholder color with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-html5-inputs-placeholder-color-with-css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its pretty simple actually:

```
$('combobox').change(function () {
   var language = $('combobox').val()

   /** Get the strings from somewhere */

   $('input[type=text]').each(function(i, input) {
       $(input).attr('placeholder', new_placeholder);
   });
});
```

Comment: it seems that you are working with just one input, but in my case I have three language and four inputs with different placeholders, so i want when a user change language the foor placeholders changes with another placeholders...

Comment: yeah, I got it, but with this line: `$('input[type=text]').each` you are looping each input text you have, that means the 4 you have. You just need to map them and put the right placeholder